# Docker image isn't building: Linux container

Tags: docker, cmd, proxy, .net-core, linux-containers

I am trying to dockerize a simple dotnetcore webapi on linux container on a windows 10 machine and whenever i build the dockerfile i get this error:

> c:\docker-tutrial>docker build -t docker-tutorial .
>
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.364MB
>
> Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1
>   Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: 
>   net/http: request canceled while
>   waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)

I tried:

> c:\docker-tutrial>docker build --build -arg
>   http_proxy=http://PROXY:8080 --build -arg
>   https_proxy=http://PROXY:8080 -t docker-tutrial .
>
> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
>   waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "docker-tutrial.dll"]
```

I believe it is a proxy issue anyideas!!

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#proxy-configuration

Comment: Thanks but It didn't work. but i already have Variable there:
http_proxy
http://proxy.com:port

https_proxy
http://proxy.com:port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I fixed the command as greyhame mentioned:
docker build --build -arg http_proxy=http://PROXY:8080 --build -arg https_proxy=https://PROXY:port -t docker-tutrial .

And i passed those two lines in the Dockerfile:
ENV HTTP_PROXY "PROXY:PORT"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "PROXY:PORT"

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same thing to me, after following various github issues I found out that the best way to overcome this problem is based on pure luck after doing these 4 steps:

1. Put 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as Docker DNS
2. Restart Docker Service
3. If you behind any firewall/proxy make sure to update those settings too.
4. Restart your computer.

These 4 steps usually solve the problem to me.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, because if i change my DNS internet won't work due to the network structure in the organization.

Comment: Oh, too bad!
I've noticed another little thing:
You tried:
`docker build --build -arg http_proxy=http://PROXY:8080 --build -arg https_proxy=http://PROXY:8080 -t docker-tutrial . `

Notice that you used "https_proxy" and you put an'http address, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, correct i fixed that issue and i passed  ENV HTTP_PROXY "http://PROXY:PORT"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://PROXY:PORT" in the docker file and it worked.

Comment: Happy if I could help :)